# Как работает input() в python?

Tags: java, python, input

[image: Интересный момент в работе input()]

Добрый день!
Предыстория:
Изучал java и наткнулся на интересный момент, что можно задать значение элемента массива при помощи следующей команды

```
array[i] = console.nextInt();
```

Решил проверить в Python и там тоже всё работает, но неожиданно выявилась интересная особенность: ввод нового *элемента* массива идёт перед вводом *места* этого самого массива.
Код выглядит так:

```
m = [1,2,3,4,5]
m[int(input("place "))] = int(input("Value "))
print(m)
```

Вопрос: почему так происходит и как работает input() в Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело не в input(), а в порядке вычисления выражений в питоне:

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while
> evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the
> left-hand side.
>
> [Python docs: Evaluation order](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)

Таким образом, `input("Value ")` выполняется сначала, а потом уже `input("place ")`.

Благодаря этому, например, можно обменять значения переменных через

`a,b = b,a`

Сначала правая часть создает set(b, a), потом выполняется присваивание.